# Switch that doesn't waste work

Tags: rxjs, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have an observable of observables, where the inner observables each produce a single expensive-to-compute value.  I want behavior like `Switch`, but where no work is wasted (`SwitchFrugal`?):

- if there is a current inner observable that is subscribed to, I want to keep receiving values from it until it completes

  - it should not be unsubscribed from as in `Switch`
- once the current inner observable completes, the latest inner observable (if there is any after the current) should be subscribed to

I have really been struggling with implementing this behavior. Is this doable using the existing operators?  Or does this need to be done "from scratch" via `Observable.Create`?

[image: Marble Diagram]

Comment: Isn't [`concatMap()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-concatMap) or [`exhaustMap()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-exhaustMap) what you're looking for?

Comment: @martin `exhaust`/`exhaustMap` are the same as `SwitchFirst` which is almost what I want, except it doesn't satisfy the second bullet point: "once the current inner observable completes, the latest inner observable (if there is any after the current) should be subscribed to"

Comment: Could you add a marble diagram of what you are looking for?

Comment: @DanielT. I added a marble diagram.

Comment: @TimothyShields - Isn't this just what `Merge` does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
const subject = new Subject();
const start = Scheduler.async.now();

// Simulated source Observable
const source = Observable
    .timer(0, 900)
    .map(i => Observable.defer(() => {
        console.log('Subscribe inner Observable:', i);
        return Observable
            .timer(0, 400)
            .take(6)
            .map(j => i.toString() + ':' + j.toString());
    }))
    .share();

source
    .merge(subject
        .withLatestFrom(source)
        .map(([v, observable]) => {
            return observable;
        })
    )
    .exhaustMap(obs => obs.finally(() => subject.next()))
    .subscribe(val => console.log(Scheduler.async.now() - start, val));
```

I'm simulating a source Observable that emits Observables. The outer Observables are emitted faster than the inner Observables complete so this should simulate your situation.

Then I'm merging the `source` into the chain but only when the `subject` emits. The Subject is then triggered in the `finally` operator.

The output is as follows:

```
Subscribe inner Observable: 0
45 '0:0'
452 '0:1'
856 '0:2'
1260 '0:3'
1665 '0:4'
2065 '0:5'
Subscribe inner Observable: 2
2069 '2:0'
2472 '2:1'
2876 '2:2'
3280 '2:3'
3683 '2:4'
4084 '2:5'
Subscribe inner Observable: 4
4086 '4:0'
4487 '4:1'
```

Notice that when the first inner Observable completes the latest emission from source is an Observable with `i === 2`. If you run this code you'll see that there's no time gap between these three emissions (jsbin is broken right now, so I can't login and make a demo):

```
2065 '0:5'
Subscribe inner Observable: 2
2069 '2:0'
```

If you compare this to the default behavior without the `merge()` you'll see that `exhaustMap` needs to wait until there's another emission from source:

```
source
    .exhaustMap(obs => obs.finally(() => subject.next()))
    .subscribe(console.log);
```

This prints the following. Notice the time gap and that it subscribed to inner Observable with `i === 3` instead of `2`:

```
Subscribe inner Observable: 0
45 '0:0'
449 '0:1'
853 '0:2'
1257 '0:3'
1659 '0:4'
2064 '0:5'
Subscribe inner Observable: 3
2748 '3:0'
3151 '3:1'
3553 '3:2'
3953 '3:3'
4355 '3:4'
4759 '3:5'
Subscribe inner Observable: 6
5458 '6:0'
5863 '6:1'
```

**Edit:**

To avoid subscribing to the same inner Observable twice (assuming these are cold Observables) I can keep track of what Observable indices I've already subscribed and what index needs to come next:

I'll make the source to emit in random intervals and less values:

```
const source = Observable.range(0, 100, Scheduler.async)
    .concatMap(i => Observable.of(i).delay(Math.random() * 3000))
    .map(i => Observable.defer(() => {
        console.log('Subscribe inner Observable:', i);
        return Observable
            .timer(0, 400)
            .take(4)
            .map(j => i.toString() + ':' + j.toString());
    }))
    .map((observable, index) => [observable, index])
    .share();
```

Then send the index we processed using `subject.next()`  and simply ignore Observables we don't want:

```
source
    .merge(subject
        .withLatestFrom(source)
        .map(([processedIndex, observableAndIndex]) => {
            let observableIndex = observableAndIndex[1];
            if (processedIndex < observableIndex) {
                return observableAndIndex;
            }
            return false;
        })
        .filter(Boolean)
    )
    .exhaustMap(([observable, index]) => observable.finally(() => subject.next(index)))
    .subscribe(val => console.log(Scheduler.async.now() - start, val));
```

The output is very similar but even when the previous Observable completes very soon we don't subscribe to it again (that's for example the time gap between Observables `1` and `2`):

```
Subscribe inner Observable: 0
2803 '0:0'
3208 '0:1'
3615 '0:2'
4016 '0:3'
Subscribe inner Observable: 1
4853 '1:0'
5254 '1:1'
5658 '1:2'
6061 '1:3'
Subscribe inner Observable: 2
7814 '2:0'
8218 '2:1'
8622 '2:2'
9026 '2:3'
Subscribe inner Observable: 3
9180 '3:0'
9583 '3:1'
9987 '3:2'
10391 '3:3'
Subscribe inner Observable: 5
10393 '5:0'
10796 '5:1'
```

Comment: This is looking very close, thanks!  I think the only problem is that, if an inner observable completes and no newer inner observables have arrived, then the same observable will be subscribed to again.  If the source observable emits a single observable and then never completes, won't this keep subscribing to the same inner observable over and over again?  (I am unable to try this out until Monday.)

Comment: @TimothyShields That's true with cold Observables (if you subscribed to a hot Observable after it completed it won't do anything). See my update, you can simply keep track of what indices you've already subscribed and eventually ignore Observables that you don't want.